# How to Load JQuery in electron webview with proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, electron

I'm setting up an electron app, with a index.html that contains a webview. The webview got a reverse proxy attached to it, changing all "/" routes. This means that I can't load any CDN libraries (JQUERY) in the webview. Is there a way to still load JQUERY? currently if I try with:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I get error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

I made the reverse proxy with express, changing route like this:

```
express.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('home.html', {root: __dirname});
})
```

Update:

Its not only jquery but also other libaries

Comment: I'm not experienced with electron,but you probably can download JQuery file's content,save it locally and load it from there such as  <script src="./jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to make the app not reliable on remote hosted libraries.

Your best shot might be to use a module bundler such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), [parcel](https://parceljs.org/) or [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en) to create a bundle of your application including the external libraries (such as jQuery, Axios or whatever code you rely on)